# Help with Limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2 n)! e^n (n)^n}{n! (2 n)^{2 n}}$

Tags: limits, infinity

Help with Limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2 n)! e^n (n)^n}{n! (2 n)^{2 n}}$$

EDIT: Posted a similar question just yesterday but bad formating from my part dropped a term, and lead me to strange places.
Honestly, I am just plain stuck, I have been hitting my head against it for $2$ days straight. I know the solution should be $2^{-1/2}$ but...

Help would be appreciated. If anyone has a Wolfram Alpha PRO account I am sure that thing churns out the solution as it is something quite basic I just don't see it and its driving me crazy.

Comment: Wanted to delete this one, but the community was way too fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $$n!\approx n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Using Stirling's approximation, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!e^nn^n}{n!(2n)^{2n}} \approx \sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n} \frac{e^nn^n}{(2n)^{2n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left( \frac{e}{n}\right)^n = \sqrt{2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Use [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):
$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n} \cdot\frac{n^n}{e^n}.$$
which implies that
$$(2n)!\sim2\sqrt{\pi n} \cdot\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{e^{2n}}.$$